# Get comma separated values from form?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've created a dynamic form for key-value pair input, some values will contain commas:

```
    using(Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "parameterForm" }))
    {
    <div id="inputBoxesDIV">
         for(int i = 0; i < Model.GetParameters().Count; i++)
           { 
                Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GetParameters().ElementAt(i).Name, new { name = "name" + i, size = 20 })
                Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GetParameters().ElementAt(i).Value, new { name = "Value" + i, size = 60 })
        }
    </div>
    }
```

I've tried to use FormCollection to get my pairs like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        foreach (var key in formCollection.AllKeys)
        {
            var value = formCollection[key];
        }

        foreach (var key in formCollection.Keys)
        {
            var value = formCollection[key.ToString()];
        }
    //etc...
```

But the FormCollection use comma separated strings so it's to no good.

Is there some way I still can use FormCollection or do you have any idea how I can solve it?

Comment: Why dont you use some model as parameter instead of FormCollection

Comment: This Razor view won't work. You cannot use such complex Lambda expression in a strongly typed helper such as TextBoxFor: `m => m.GetParameters().ElementAt(i).Name`. It will throw an exception. Also you cannot override the `name` property as you are trying to. The helper will always use the lambda expression to calculate the view.

Comment: How can i achieve that?

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, do we have any reference to know what kind of lambda expression can be supported in razor view? So we could avoid mistakes in future. You always rock :)

Comment: @JohanMagnusson, I am not aware of a reference but you could use indexer access and property access expressions. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to generate a view based on dynamically generated model, For that you shouldn't give chance to make changes to name part of keyvalue pair right, so remove textbox for that like,

```
using(Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "parameterForm" }))
    {
    <div id="inputBoxesDIV">
         for(int i = 0; i < Model.GetParameters().Count; i++)
           { 
<label>Model.GetParameters().ElementAt(i).Name</label>

                Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.GetParameters().ElementAt(i).Value, new { name =Model.GetParameters().ElementAt(i).Name , size = 60 })
        }
    </div>
    }
```

so user will make changes to value textboxes, so after he submits your able to read all values using key names,

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection formCollection)
    {
        foreach (var key in formCollection.AllKeys)
        {
            var value = formCollection[key];
        }

        foreach (var key in formCollection.Keys)
        {
            var value = formCollection[key.ToString()];
        }
}
```

If you want to give the users the ability to modify both name and value in key value pair, Then you should try like this,

```
     using(Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "parameterForm" }))
        {
        <div id="inputBoxesDIV">
             for(int i = 0; i < Model.GetParameters().Count; i++)
               { 

<input type="text" name="@String.Format("name{0}",i)" value="@Model.GetParameters().ElementAt(i).Name" size="20"/>

                   <input type="text" name="@String.Format("value{0}",i)" value="@Model.GetParameters().ElementAt(i).Value" size="60"/>
            }
        </div>
        }
```

and in your post action,

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(FormCollection formCollection)
    {


        for(int i=0;i<formCollection.AllKeys.Length;i++)
        {
            var value = formCollection["value"+i];
            var name=formCollection["name"+i];
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The first part is not an option, the user has to type both name and value =/ And I don't see how the second would help, I still get comma separated strings, and the user should be allowed to use commas in value.

Comment: Actually both "var value = formCollection["value"+i];" and "var name=formCollection["name"+i];" returns null (It loops four times returning null every time)

Comment: Instead of Html helper for textbox try raw html syntax, like `<input type="text" name="@String.Format("name{0}",i)"/>` like that..

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use model binding:

```
public class KeyValue
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
public class Test
{
    public IEnumerable<KeyValue> KV { get; set; }
}
```

And in view:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
    for (var kv = 0; kv < Model.KV.Count(); ++kv)
    {
        @Html.TextBox("KV[" + kv + "].Name", Model.KV.ElementAt(kv).Name);
        @:<br />
        @Html.TextBox("KV[" + kv + "].Value", Model.KV.ElementAt(kv).Value);
        @:<br />
    }

    @:<input type="submit" />
}
```

And in cotroller get your Model:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Test model)
    {
        ...
    }
```